# Managing Linux Server for a Website

Tags: linux, lamp

I'm currently building a website using the LAMP stack and would really like to learn how to manage Linux servers running my website.

My question is, what certifications and online videos are available for teaching me how to manage Linux servers for a website that is rapidly growing?

For example, MCITP certification may be considered good training for managing Windows servers. If so, what is the equivalent gold standard for managing Linux servers? I was particularly interested in LinuxCBT videos, are they relevant for this purpose? If so, which LinuxCBT videos would you recommend? If not, what would you recommend?

Comment: LinuxCBT sounds like a really niche form of S&M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you need certification for career development purposes, I would focus more on gaining the practical knowledge needed to manage your operations.  With Red Hat training and certification, there is a lot of information that you will never use in managing web operations.

So instead of certification routes, I would look for specific resources.

I would setup a development system that is a clone of your production environment and use it for testing and training.

Key areas you need to manage web ops:

- Apache Configuration, Diagnostics, Performance Tuning
- MySQL - Table repair, backup/restore, performance tuning
- PHP - Configuration management, PECL/PEAR add-ons, OpCode Caches, Performance tuning
- OS - Patch management, resource monitoring, logging
- Security - Basic firewall (iptables), ssh, network and process reporting basics

There is far more but this is a check list we use when hiring new sysadmins to support our clients who run various web operations.

With the certification route, you may find some of these topics are lightly covered or delayed to an advanced course.  So may be better just to pick and choose the topics you need.

For a high level overview of web ops, take a look at:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920000136.do

Not a "how to do" book but will give you a good ideal of the scope of what web ops management entails.  You can then pick the parts you want to take on yourself and outsource the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that internet is full of resources on LAMP. There are plenty of tutorials available on same and I would recommend you to go through it. With respect to LAMP or most of the Linux technologies, you not only need to learn the right thing but you also need to know how to avoid the wrong actions. Most of the paid courses fail to address the latter case. Just go on youtube and see some [videos](http://www.youtube.com/results?gcx=c&q=how%20to%20create%20lamp%20server) on LAMP. Read out a few tutorials and you would be good to go. 
However if you must go for [LinuxCBT](http://www.linuxcbt.com/products_linuxcbt.php) then module 8 is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

LinuxCBT are the KING of learning about linux system administration, after that comes LPIC training material.